# How can I install beta versions of vmc?

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

I am trying to install the 0.4.0.beta version of vmc, but after installation I still have old version.

```
> gem install vmc --pre
[...]
Installing RDoc documentation for vmc-0.4.0.beta.90...
>  ~  $ vmc --version
vmc 0.3.23
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't have any experience with Ruby, I am installing this tool in order to manage my cloudfoundry app. (I am using MacOS X)

Update: I followed the steps here to install ruby/rvm and the gem https://stackoverflow.com/a/11573805/156300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run the beta version, I had to create the following file

```
mkdir ~/.vmc
touch ~/.vmc/use-ng
```

I found out about this by digging though the source files.

Comment: Edi is correct. In order to correct the very bleeding edge features of vmc, you'll need to create that folder/directory. This is quite "undocumented" but you can find out more about it in various presentations, e.g. search for CloudFoundry at SpringOne 2012

Comment: Yes, we retain backward-compatibility with the old-style commands while we work on the beta version. Do provide feedback on what you think of the new style commands and output!

Comment: creating `~/.vmc/use-ng` didn't work for me, still shows default vmc version.  vmc 0.4.2, os x lion.

Comment: Actually, I tried this with a fresh gemset using rvm and it worked, so it must be something with my previously-installed (and recently updated) vmc.